# Несколько представлений для задач в Битрикс24

Tags: windows, 1с, битрикс24, настройки, crm

Есть представление **Мой план**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть, если я захочу несколько представлений типа **Мой план**, для каждого из которых будут свои стадии? Как получить несколько представлений?